# React.js - convert .jsx to .js

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

I'm totally new to `React`...how do I convert a `.jsx` file to `.js`?

I tried to use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-react-jsx/) via CLI but the command doesn't even work:

```
babel --plugins transform-react-jsx board.jsx
```

I also tried replacing "babel" for "npx" in the above command, but it always retuns "Path must be a string. Received undefined".

I ran the code in the folder and also trying to pass the path, but none worked.

Does anyone have a tutorial, working example or can help me to make this work?

Link with .jsx file I want to compile:
https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/tree/master/stories/src/board

[image]

Comment: The error above is from `npx`. You haven't touched babel yet.

Comment: Are you using `webpack`?

Comment: No, I'm not....

Comment: @Mr.Mister your cmd screenshot and your question text disagree. Please clarify.

Comment: I installed babel locally in my project, then I ran the command "babel --plugins transform-react-jsx board.js", but it doesn't work, it says it's not recognized as a command. Then people are saying I have to pass the path where babel is locally installed, and i tried "./node_modules/.bin/babel --plugins transform-react-jsx board.js", but still the same error message. How should I type the command?

Answer (score -1):

I don’t think that main point of stackoverflow is to provide how to guides which could be googled in 5 seconds on google. But here you have a link https://medium.freecodecamp.org/part-1-react-app-from-scratch-using-webpack-4-562b1d231e75